# jquery bulk upload javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running into a javascript issue where it's getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  With my reading I think it's the order of when I am trying to do $(document).ready before the javascript is loaded up but I am not sure what to do about it.  I have tried moving the jquery and the fileuploadmulti above the script but then I get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uploadFile is not a function" and then I go down the road of chicken and egg and don't know what is correct.  Any help or point in the right direction would be helpful.  Thank you.

```
<script>
//This is where my error shows up
$(document).ready(function(){
    var settings = {
        url: "/index.php/upload",
        method: "POST",
        allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
        fileName: "myfile",
        multiple: true,
        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
        {
            $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
        },
        afterUploadAll:function()
        {
            alert('All Files uploaded');
        },
        onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
        {
            $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
        }
    };
    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);
});
</script>

<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/fileuploadmulti.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxed link">
    <div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload</div>
    <div id="status"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>Adding pages to <?php echo $model->name; ?></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange to find almost exactly "your" code in a [phpgang.com example](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-jquery-ajax-using-php_453.html). Even the typo in `#mulitplefileuploader` is the same.

The only difference I see is the name of the library. You use `fileuploadmulti.min.js` instead of `jquery.fileuploadmulti.min.js`... Did you renamed the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check whether JQuery is loaded or not.

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And wrap the all JQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){  \\code here   });` function.

`$(...).uploadFile is not a function error` because you are not loading the fileupload plugin properly.

Check all script tag URL'S are right or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `$` before including `jQuery`. Try to include it before.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include

`<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="/js/fileuploadmulti.min.js"></script>`

before `$(document).ready(function(){  });`

Comment: I have tried this and I get a "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).uploadFile is not a function"